# Is tar --list efficient?

Tags: tar

I previously asked [how to create an index of a multi-volume archive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307086/how-can-i-get-tar-to-build-an-index-for-a-multi-volume-archive). That question contained the assumption that using `tar --list` after writing my volumes would have to re-read all my data and hence be slow

However, is that true? Will it have to re-read every byte, or is GNU tar intelligent enough to seek over archive members and hence list the archive contents very quickly?

I did a bit of testing with a 35GB tar file and the result (completion within 2 seconds) seems to indicate that `--list` is indeed fast, though I don't completely trust my testing methodology and couldn't rule out the influence of caching or something else I don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the archive is seekable, `tar` will take advantage of that to skip through the archive. So if your archive is an uncompressed file, `tar --list` will skip from one header to the next and process the file very quickly.

See also the `-n` option. (And look for "seek" in the [`tar` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).)